# Force Close error coming when using addTextChangedListtener for an edit box

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I want to validate the edittexts for "`username`" and "`password`" field.I don't want the user to leave username and password as blank.I found in this site that using `TextWatcher` n adding `addTextChangedListener` we can handle this..but am getting **Force Close error**..I am very new to android and this is my first application.Please tell me where I am going wrong.I am having the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements android.text.TextWatcher {

 public String userString;
 public EditText edt_Username;
 public EditText edt_pwd;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // for validating username textbox

          edt_Username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    edt_Username.addTextChangedListener(this);



    //for validating pwd textbox
     edt_pwd=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwd);
    edt_pwd.addTextChangedListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}   
public void login(View view)
{

            Intent intent=new Intent(this,Leave_form.class);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_leave_form);
            startActivity(intent);

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if( edt_Username.getText().toString().equals(null)||edt_pwd.getText().toString().equals(null))
    {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "All Fields Required.", 
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: What exception is causing the error, and on what line?

Comment: can you post the error in logcat entry also?

Comment: user entered value is in Editable s not in edt_Username.getText(), so try like this s.toString().equals(" ")

Comment: i cleared the project..now the force close error is solved.But the toast is not wrking..it is still allowing to proceed to next screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,Leave_form.class); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_leave_form);
startActivity(intent);
```

You are calling in login() method setContentView() that can be called only once! In **onCreate()** method.

Solution is to remove this line and just start new `Activity` as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Leave_form.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```

and then call

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_leave_form);
```

in **Leave_form class** in onCreate() method.

### Update:

Also in your code is more things broken:

```
edt_Username.getText().toString().equals(null)
```

If you want to determine whether textbox is empty just use:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edt_User.getText().toString()) && ...) {
   Toast.makeText(context, "Fields are required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Note:** `edt_Username.getText()` will be always not null.

Comment: Thank u so mch Sajmon..i think it shud wrk now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the text is null:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
{

   if( edt_Username.getText() == null || edt_Username.getText().toString().equals("") || edt_pwd.getText() == null || edt_pwd.getText().toString().equals(""))
   {
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "All Fields Required.", 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all allow user to enter their name and password and put a button for login when they click the button validate the username and password.